# Accounts database design

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, accounts

Hello everyone i am developing an accounts package for my company using Sql Server 2008 and VB.Net.

I need some help regarding the database design.

I have the following tables

```
AccountsGroupMaster

GroupId int
GroupName nvarchar(50)
ParentGroupId int
CatId int
PrimaryGroup bit
CreatedByUser nvarchar(50)
CreatedOn datetime
```

The above table will store the Groups for the accounts eg: Current Assets etc.

```
Accounts Table

AccCode nvarchar(6)
AccountName nvarchar(30)
ParentAcc nvarchar(6)
GroupId int
```

The above table stores the Accounts/Ledgers .

```
VoucherMain

VoucherNo bigint
VoucherDate datetime
DebitCredit int (0 for Credit 1 for Debit)
AccCode nvarchar(6) (Account Code to be debited/Credited)
UserID nvarchar(30)

VoucherDetails

VoucherNo bigint
SlNo int
AccCode nvarchar(6) (Debit this account if account in VoucherMain credited/ Credit this account if account in VoucherMain Debited)
Amount decimal(18, 2)
Narration nvarchar(MAX)
```

The above two tables store the transactions.The above two tables linked by the VoucherNo columns

Now my question is whether i should maintain all the bank accounts in the accounts table or should i have a separate table for the bank accounts.
As each bank account should have its respective ledgers.

Please help me in the design of this database.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is a `BankAccount` different than an `Account`?  If it's a different entity entirely then it would probably call for its own table.  If it's just a certain *kind* of `Account` then it might not.  In that case, there could be other options:

For example, you could add an `AccountType` to the `Account` table to determine which ones are `BankAccount` types and which ones are not.

Or, if the difference is more than just a type flag and includes additional Account-level columns of data which are applicable *only* to that specific type of `Account` instances, then you might make a sub-table.  It would be a `BankAccounts` table, but its primary key would also be a foreign key to the `Accounts` table, creating an enforced 0-1 relationship between the two.

Then, whenever creating a `BankAccount` record you'd first add a record to the `Accounts` table, get the generated key, and use that key to add a record to the `BankAccounts` table.